# Build a CMake project using multiple libraries(built or not/source code)

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, cmake

I want to create a Visual Studio Project which will utilize 4 different Libraries.

Library 1: I have got it from github and I have only src code files+CMakeLists.txt which calls libraries like opencv/opengl/glut and also library 2.I don't have any dlls,bins etc.

Library 2: Is openCV 3.0.I have both build files and src files.

Library 3: I have ready files-->include,bin,dlls etc

Library 4: I have ready files-->include,bin,dlls etc

How can I start with CMake to combine all the above libraries?
I should start a brand new project and write a CMakelists file which will call for all 4 libraries stated above? Can I use immediately the 1st library which hasn't been compiled? Any CMakeLists.txt example to get started for combining all these?

Comment: ***I should start a brand new project and write a CMakelists file which will call for all 4 libraries stated above?*** Yes.

Comment: ***Can I use immediately the 1st library which hasn't been compiled?*** You can use externalproject_add to pull these into your project however I would just build them separately.

Comment: ***Any CMakeLists.txt example to get started for combining all these?*** There are 100s of CMake examples on the kitware wiki. None of them will combine all of these but give you the idea how to use external libraries and frameworks in your code using a CMakeLists.txt to generate the project file for your application.